# htaccess friend url in php

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm trying to create some 'friendly URL' to my site. But I'm not sure what to do. Below as my site is structured:

[image: demo1]

[image: demo2]

[image: demo3]

To enter a page for example: `localhost/study/dashboard/client/network.php`

I wanted to write to localhost/study/network. Following the same format to some other pages. I wanted to block direct access to critical files, such as user-proc.php, api.php for example.

What I tried to do:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule    ^study/network?$    network.php
```

I put a .htaccess file in each directory (administration, client), but that blocked my website for full. I could not even more access for localhost/study/administration/network.php.

Comment: You should try to narrow this question down. We cannot just guess what all of your desired translations are. How do we know that `localhost/study/network` shouldn't go to `localhost/study/dashboard/administration/network.php` other than the fact that you explicitly said so? You have not been explicit about the other cases. Are you wanting to block all access to the `administration` directory? What exactly is the definition of "critical files"? As it stands, this question is too broad.

Comment: I gave only one example that if possible , you only help me with it ... for the rest I would try to do. Just as I tried but I had no success. About critical files, I said: "user-proc.php, api.php" or others like "something-proc.php"..

Comment: And on top of the images.. I said, " I want to rewrite urls "... And I gave the example of how I would like to rewrite the url to that page `localhost/study/dashboard/client/network.php` to `localhost/study/network`

Comment: If you only want the answer to rewriting that one specific case, then please remove everything else from your question, as it is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

To rewrite from `/study/network` to `/study/dashboard/client/network.php`, you can just put the two URLs, pattern and substitution, in a [`RewriteRule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)

```
RewriteRule ^study/network$ /study/dashboard/client/network.php [L]
```

This is for this specific case. To do this for any combination, you must capture the two parts from the request URI pattern and then use this in the substitution part

```
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/(.*?)$ /$1/dashboard/client/$2.php [L]
```

This looks for any two component part `(...)/(...)` and uses this - `$1` and `$2` - in the replacement.

---

To prevent access to some URI, you do almost the same, but omit the substitution part with a `- (dash)`, and use the flag [`F|forbidden`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_f)

```
RewriteRule user-proc.php - [F]
```

Comment: But if I do "RewriteRule user-proc.php - [F]" when a file send data via post to this page will appear unauthorized access. What do I do?

Comment: You wrote "I wanted to block direct access to critical files, such as user-proc.php". If this is not what you want, try to clarify your question.

Comment: Sure :/. Sorry Olaf.

Comment: Sorry if I sounded too harsh, no need to apologize.